# C# & Mapscript - Setting Environment Variables At Runtime

Tags: c#, mapscript

I am working on an application that makes use of the c# Mapscript bindings.  When I manually set and/or append to the GDAL_DATA, GDAL_DRIVER_PATH, PROJ_LIB, and PATH environment variables - the application code works beautifully.

For a number of reasons, I am trying to avoid permanently setting/changing these environment variables.  I am [under the impression](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/96xafkes.aspx) that by using the .NET frameworks Environment.SetEnvironmentVariable method, that I should be able to set these environment variables at runtime for the current process.

This approach seems to work in some capacity - as the mapscript objects initialize properly (i.e., I dont get PInvoke errors...etc). In my code snippet below, I get an error at map.draw() complaining about GDAL_DATA and gcs.csv.

```
// add some new environment vars
// TODO check if they may already exist - in which case append to
Environment.SetEnvironmentVariable("GDAL_DATA",MY_GDAL_DATA_PATH)
Environment.SetEnvironmentVariable("GDAL_DRIVER_PATH",MY_GDAL_DRIVER_PATH)
Environment.SetEnvironmentVariable("PROJ_LIB",MY_PROJ_LIB_PATH)

// append to existing PATH variable
string pathVariable = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("PATH")
pathVariable += MY_PATH_VARS
Environment.SetEnvironmentVariable("PATH",MY_PATH_VARS)

mapObj map = new mapObj(transmitterMapFile);
map.setSize(request.Width, request.Height);
map.setExtent(extent[0], extent[1], extent[2], extent[3]);

imageObj img = map.draw();
```

Does anyone see something wrong with this approach?  Or is there a better way to set these variables at runtime?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I use a similar approach in Python with MapScript on Windows and it works fine.

Careful with the following code:

```
pathVariable += MY_PATH_VARS
Environment.SetEnvironmentVariable("PATH", MY_PATH_VARS)
```

I believe it should be:

```
pathVariable += MY_PATH_VARS
Environment.SetEnvironmentVariable("PATH", pathVariable)
```

I'd look at the C# sourcecode for [GdalGoneWild](https://bitbucket.org/bjartn/gdalgonewild) - *"Using GDAL in .NET without a big headache"*

The [environment variable setup](https://bitbucket.org/bjartn/gdalgonewild/src/f8701045ccee/src/GdalGoneWild.Client/GdalEnvironment.cs) code should be of particular interest. The author also mentions in an associated [blog post](http://bjarte.com/post/gdal-in-csharp):

> One little strange thing I noticed was that I was not able to set up
>   the GDAL_DATA environment variable programmatically. So instead I used
>   Gdal.SetConfigOption which overrides the environment variable.

A couple of final things to check. Are you registering the GDAL drivers elsewhere in your code?

```
Gdal.AllRegister();
```

Finally the PATH must contain semi-colons between each specified path.

```
C:\dir1;C:\dir2
```

Comment: Thanks for the response.  I had a typo in my code snippet - I am correctly referencing the appended 'pathVariable'.  However, my code still bombs at imageObj img = map.draw().

Comment: Links attached - looks like there may well be an issue with GDAL_DATA